# Efficient implementation of a Bloom filter in C?

Tags: c, bloom-filter

This question has been asked previously but there was no answer for it at that time so I decided to ask it again.

I need an efficient implementation of a Bloom filter in C (not C++). If there is no such thing available, I would not mind implementing one, if given some good reference so that it doesn't take too much of my time.

I want to use this data structure for inserts and tests in a ratio (1:20k), so primarily it is test-intensive. The data to be tested is 64 bit integers.

Comment: It is probabilistic. If you want exact answer, use Union Find Disjoint Set. Search for this on topcoder, there should be some tutorial for it.

Comment: If you're writing C, this is not the kind of thing you need a general library for. It should be less than 100 lines of code, and should take less time to write than integrating a third-party library. Just read your favorite description of the algorithm on Wikipedia or similar..

Comment: @R writing it will take less time that I know but efficiently writing it so that it scales well is a problem. I have to test membership of data in the order of 10^7 and make this query faster than count(*) query on the result of a equi join. I can't afford to lose even a ms in my implementation

Comment: The efficiency is in both whatever hash function(s) you choose (fast but with low probability of collision), and the efficiency of representing the filter (e.g., bitmap if you're not doing a counting filter); other than that, there's not much more optimization that can be done.

Comment: can you tell me some places I can read about hash functions suitable for this purpose

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam yes: google; I honestly don't have a more authoritative answer than that, although a quick-and-dirty one would be feeding a pointer to the Jenkins Hash Function (http://http://www.burtleburtle.net/bob/hash/doobs.html) and using that as the index for marking the filter; however, that's only a 1-dimensional bloom filter, and you could do better with other approaches, IMO

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam er, was supposed to say that you should feed the pointer to Jenkins' mix() macro, not the full-on hash function...

Comment: thanks a lot. when I write one I will definately post it here.

Answer (score 17):

I have a stand-alone plain C library here which may be of use:
https://github.com/jvirkki/libbloom

Answer (score 4):

Not to do too much self-promotion, but I've written a plugin for the [Geany editor/IDE](http://geany.org/) that filters out duplicate text lines, it uses a Bloom filter.

The implementation is in C, and you can find it [right here on GitHub](https://github.com/unwind/geanyuniq). It's GPL v3, so depending on your exact needs you may or may not be able to use it.

Some notes about my implementation:

- It's designed to filter strings, and doesn't abstract the key type. This means you're going to have to modify the key handling to suit your needs.
- It supports un-characteristic semantics, you can actually use it for totally non-probabilistic existance-testing if you want to (see the `BloomContains` callback function pointer used by `bloom_filter_new()`). Just pass `NULL` to get a "pure" filter.
- The string hash function is [MurmurHash2](https://sites.google.com/site/murmurhash/) by Austin Appleby. I evaluated the more current MurmurHash3, but version 2 was easier to work with.
- To fit in the Geany eco system, this code uses [GLib](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/) types throughout.

It hasn't been heavily tuned for performance, but should be okay. I would appreciate any feedback you might have after testing it, of course!

Comment: Hey, thanks it can be very helpful indeed. i will give it a try and tell you about it.

Comment: can you suggest can some other libraries for high performance other than glib

Comment: can you suggest any particular motive of using glib library except for it makes code portable.

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam Well, the standard rationale for a library of course applies: someone else has already solved a bunch of things, so I don't need to reinvent the wheel. Also, the code is from a plug-in to an IDE that's based on GTK+/GLib, so it would be strange *not* to use GLib.

Answer (score 2):

Chromium has one in C++

[github link](https://github.com/adobe/chromium/blob/master/chrome/browser/safe_browsing/bloom_filter.h)

Comment: Man, they really need to include Bob Jenkins' copyright for their use of his (public domain) hashing function...

Answer (score 1):

Several Bloom filter implementations, and alternative algorithms, are available in this project: https://github.com/FastFilter/fastfilter_cpp

Covered are the regular Bloom filter, blocked Bloom filter, cuckoo filter, Golomb coded set, and others. It is C++, but the main algorithms are easy to port to C.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but for reference, here are some github search results.

A simple  search on github for 'bloomfilter' yields a ton of results (for C) :

https://github.com/search?q=extension%3Ac+bloomfilter&type=Code&ref=searchresults

This is for **REFERENCE** only.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how efficient it is, because I haven't done extensive benchmarks, but I did document the chain of thoughts on "How To Implement a Bloom Filter in C" [in this article](https://www.andreinc.net/2022/03/01/on-implementing-bloom-filters-in-c), with the [associated GitHub repo](https://github.com/nomemory/bloomfilters-c).

The code is simplified and it works on `char*`, but it can be extended for `void*` with a little bit of tweaking.

The main approach would be to look for a *Bit Vector* (also known as a [Bit Array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_array)) implementation that will represent the underlying memory structure for your Bloom Filter.

There are a few options here:

- Using something that exists already (e.g.: [xtrapbits.h](https://github.com/iplinux/x11proto-trap/blob/master/xtrapbits.h)
- Writing it yourself. That's a good exercise for practising bitwise operations.

The second step is to find yourself some good hash functions. Usually, I recommend using [MurmurHash](https://github.com/aappleby/smhasher/blob/master/src/MurmurHash3.cpp), [SpookyHash](http://burtleburtle.net/bob/hash/spooky.html), or [FNV](http://www.isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/fnv/).

After having those in place, the code is easier to write, write yourself a struct like this one:

```c
typedef uint32_t (*hash32_func)(const void *data, size_t length);

typedef struct bloom_filter_s {
    bit_vect *vect; // <--- Implementation dependent
    hash32_func *hash_functions;
    size_t num_functions;
    size_t num_items;
} bloom_filter;


bloom_filter *bloom_filter_new(size_t size, size_t num_functions, ...);
bloom_filter *bloom_filter_new_default(size_t size);
void bloom_filter_free(bloom_filter *filter);
void bloom_filter_put(bloom_filter *filter, const void *data, size_t length);
void bloom_filter_put_str(bloom_filter *filter, const char *str);
bool bloom_filter_test(bloom_filter *filter, const void *data, size_t lentgth);
bool bloom_filter_test_str(bloom_filter *filter, const char *str);
```

And then start implementing the methods.

For example, adding an element to the Bloom filter should be as simple as:

```c
void bloom_filter_put(bloom_filter *filter, const void *data, size_t length){
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < filter->num_functions; i++) {
        uint32_t cur_hash = filter->hash_functions[i](data, length);
        bit_vect_set1(filter->vect, cur_hash % filter->vect->size);
        filter->num_items++;
    }
}
```

Also, contrary to popular belief you don't need K hash functions, you only need two and you can generate the others from them. [Source here](https://www.andreinc.net/2022/03/01/on-implementing-bloom-filters-in-c#re-use-hash-functions).